# Use Roboeletric with Gradle

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, robolectric

I'm trying to setup **Gradle** to run Android test using **Roboelectric** mocking framework.

I have an Eclipse workspace with this structure:

```
MyApp
    src
    gen
    test
    ....

MyAppTest
    libs
    test (source folder linked to MyApp.test)
    ....
```

Tests runs fine in Eclipse manually configuring build path.

How can I configure Gradle build scripts in MyAppTest to run tests in MyApp project using Roboelectric?

Comment: You should make MyAppTest project dependent on MyApp project

Comment: For example like here - https://github.com/Goddchen/Android-Gradle-Examples/tree/master/Gradle%20Library%20Projects

Comment: @EugenMartynov in MyAppTest I've configured settings.gradle with includeFlat 'MyApp' and I've also set up the dependency in build.gradle (compile project(':MyApp')) with no luck. When I launch the test task in Gradle no test is run.

Comment: Ah, that is because android plugin doesn't support unit test. Take a look here for changes in `build.gradle` https://github.com/emartynov/UrlSetter/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working based on this [solution](http://kostyay.name/android-studio-robolectric-gradle-getting-work)

In summary, try adding the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    testLocal {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Dependencies for your production code here.
    compile 'some.library'

    // localTest dependencies, including dependencies required by production code.
    testLocalCompile 'some.library'
    testLocalCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testLocalCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
    testLocalCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.2'
}

task localTest(type: Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.testLocal.output.classesDir

    android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { dir ->
        def buildDir = dir.getAbsolutePath().split('/')
        buildDir =  (buildDir[0..(buildDir.length - 4)] + ['build', 'classes', 'debug']).join('/')

        sourceSets.testLocal.compileClasspath += files(buildDir)
        sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath += files(buildDir)
    }

    classpath = sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn localTest
```

Don't forget to alter your `*Test.java` to `@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)`:

```
public class RobolectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    public RobolectricGradleTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        String pwd = YourApplication.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String root = pwd + "../../../src/main/";

        return new AndroidManifest(
                Fs.fileFromPath(root + "AndroidManifest.xml"),
                Fs.fileFromPath(root + "res"),
                Fs.fileFromPath(root + "assets"));
    }
}
```

You will then be able to run your test via `gradle compileDebugJava localTest`.  If I remember correctly, this will require a newer version of gradle (perhaps 1.8 or 1.9)

Comment: Note that [`RobolectricGradleTestRunner`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin/blob/master/README.md) is only required for [Robolectric 2.2](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/744).  @Eugen Martynov may have a better solution if you are ready to use `org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT`